# concatenate values of string column and long column in panda dataframe

Tags: pandas, ipython

I have a pandas data frame which doesn't have an index yet (just artificial 1,2,3,.. index)

Column 'store', 'style' is string, column 'color', 'size' is a long int.
None of them are unique by themselves, but the concatenation of them are unique.

I want to concatenate them to produce an index, but

```
df2['store']+df2['style']+str(df2['color'])+str(df2['size'])
```

or

```
df2['store']+df2['style']+df2['color'].to_string()+df2['size'].to_string()
```

both doesn't work. I think it takes the whole column, force it to become a string and concatenate which results in weird symbols. And merges doesn't work correctly.

What's the correct way to concatenate a string column and a long column?

Comment: Few rows of data will be helpful to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be:

```
df2['store'] + df2['style'] + df2['color'].astype(str) + df2['size'].astype(str)
```

Explanation: `str(df2['size'])` will make a string representation of the full column (one string, comparable as to what you see if you print the string), while `.astype(str)` will convert all values of the series to strings.
`to_string` gives the same result as `str()` (but takes optional parameters to control the result)